# creating a pseudo linked list in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table that has the following columns

```
table: route
columns: id, location, order_id
```

and it has values such as

```
id, location, order_id
1, London, 12
2, Amsterdam, 102
3, Berlin, 90
5, Paris, 19
```

Is it possible to do a sql select statement in postgres that will return each row along with the id with the next highest order_id? So I want something like...

```
id, location, order_id, next_id
1, London, 12, 5
2, Amsterdam, 102, NULL
3, Berlin, 90, 2
5, Paris, 19, 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select 
  id, 
  location, 
  order_id,
  lag(id) over (order by order_id desc) as next_id
from your_table
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool, I've never heard of the lag function. How preformant is the function? Does it do lag() once for the whole table? Or will it be doing an order for each row?

Comment: It is an **analytic function**. In this case, the engine order the rows, and then for every rows gets the value from precedent row. So, you have a single full scan of the table and a sort.

Comment: and if you want to lag more than one column, i.e. add a lag(location) over (order by order_id desc) as next_location. Will that do a second sort? And if I also want previous id and location, will that do a third and fourth sort?

Comment: No, will not. It is a single sort defined by `order by order_id desc`

Comment: if I do lag(location) over (order by order_id asc) to get previous, will that reuse the existing sort? Or should I use lag(location, -1) over (order by order_id desc)?

Comment: lag gets previous, and lead gets next. About sort: it is a single sort:  `(order by order_id desc)`. It will be another sort if you write ` order by id desc` or `order by location`

Comment: [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html) , or this can be useful: [oracle analytic functions](http://orafaq.com/node/55)

Answer (score 1):

Creating testbed first:

```
CREATE TABLE route (id int4, location varchar(20), order_id int4);
INSERT INTO route VALUES
    (1,'London',12),(2,'Amsterdam',102),
    (3,'Berlin',90),(5,'Paris',19);
```

The query:

```
WITH ranked AS (
    SELECT id,location,order_id,rank() OVER (ORDER BY order_id)
      FROM route)
SELECT b.id, b.location, b.order_id, n.id
  FROM ranked b
  LEFT JOIN ranked n ON b.rank+1=n.rank
  ORDER BY b.id;
```

You can read more on the window functions in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html).

Answer (score 0):

yes:

```
select * ,
(select top 1 id from routes_table where order_id > main.order_id order by 1 desc)
from routes_table main
```

Comment: Yeah I came up with something similar to this, but I was thinking that the performance will be terrible what with having to do the subquery for every row

Comment: This is not a valid PostgreSQL construct.

Comment: This was my query that is valid PostgreSQL: 
select * from mytable l left join mytable r on r.order_id = (select min(s.order_id) from mytable s where s.order_id > l.order_id)