# SQL within Django - "order" field for the records in table - defined by user, can be arbitrary, changes constantly - how do I do this?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

So I have an application in which a user creates a list.  The user also orders the items in the list and can add and remove items from the list.  If the user logs out and then logs in from another device, the list needs to be presented in the same order it was in before.

So far I have approached this problem by just adding a field called "order" to the records in the table.  Let's say I have a list of 800 items.  If the user deletes item 4, I cannot simply remove the record from the table -- I also have to update 796 records to reflect the new order of those items.  If the user then adds an item, I have to not only add a record to the table, I have to update every item with an order count higher than the position the new item was added.

My approach seems expensive and naive to me.  Is there some clever and efficient way to approach this problem?  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Related: [creating a pseudo linked list in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348778/creating-a-pseudo-linked-list-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the equivalent of a [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) where each node has a pointer to its previous and next node.

- Inserting a node is only updating previous/next pointers so no need to update anything else.
- Removing a node is only updating previous/next pointers (by having them point to each other) so no need to update anything else.

So instead of one `order` field you need two fields `previous` and `next` that indicate the previous and next node in the ordered list.

Comment: Wow, perfect.  I can't believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: Depending on what else you need to do, a singly linked list may suffice as well.